# Equal numbers are not equal - javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, numbers, equals

I am facing a strange problem. I have two Numbers (both 1) and they are not equal.

```
> step.id
> Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
> 
> $scope.process.currentStep
> Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
> 
> step.id === $scope.process.currentStep
> false
```

Comment: Its pretty essential that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this sort of question.

Answer (score 0):

While your question does lack detail a bit, your problem seems to be due to the usage of `===`. This is a strict checking mechanism, which means that it does not perform type/object conversion. So if the two entities are of not the same object, they are not equal. By that logic,from console.

```
"1"==1
true
"1"===1
false
```

Comment: Looks like his console is calling both if them type `Number` so although you're right, it doesn't look like the case here. Until we see a reproducable example we wont know

Comment: sadly this doesnt change anything. i am going to convert it to a string to compare. nothing else seems to be working.

The variables comes out of a blackbox and i only know the type by "typeof" or print them out in chrome-console. But with "toString" it works.

Maybe it will be good to encapsulate it to make it easier to fix later.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems a bit dirty to me but for now it works and it is encapsulate to fix it easily.

I wrote an extension for the Number-Type to compare two numbers.

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'Equals', {
   value: function (compareTo) {
      'use strict';

       var number = this;
       if (typeof (number) === 'number' || typeof (compareTo) === 'number') {
          return number === compareTo;
       }

       return number.toString() === compareTo.toString();
   },
   writable: true,
   configurable: true,
   enumerable: false
});
```